# how to read sharepoint list items status and update in another list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-rest-api

```
**List A**
ID    Color    UpdateStatus
111   black 
222   red   

**List B**
LookuptoID(List A)  status
111                 Not started
111                 Not started
111                 In progress
```

I need to read List B items that is lookup to List A
lets say the items for lookupid 111 and update List A Updatestatus to Inprogress. (The logic for updatestatus is I need to read the List B LookuptoID 111 and check values for status if it has all the lookupvalues status to Not started it will be Not started, if it has Not started and In progress it needs to update List A Updatestatus to inprogess.
I tried designer workflow and didn’t work since it works for only one to one relationships and in my req List B can have multiples look up id.
Any guidance will be hugely appreciated!

Comment: @Tole, can you give us more details, please? Do you need to do it using Designer Workflows or REST? When you are using REST, are you using C#, JavaScript, PowerShell? Do you need to do it one time or setup some recurring timer job? What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I tried designer workflow but couldn't find logic to iterate to next item. 
For List B, I need to check status for item 1, item 2 and 3 so and then get sum of status and update to List A. I am limited to using JS only. No options from back-end code or powershell. Working on SP 2019 on-premise version. It would be recurring instances.